# Can't configure APC for PHP

Tags: php, apc, ini, php-extension

I am having a very weird issue with my fresh dedicated server.
It has Plesk 11 installed and I am trying to install APC in it. Everything went fine and I can see the APC configuration on the `phpinfo()`, but I am not able to configure it! I am trying with every way possible but the config shown in the phpinfo doesn't change. It doesn't show that the `apc.ini` config file is loaded in the additional ini files, but if I comment the `extension=apc.so` line inside the file, the APC goes down.

Here comes my apc.ini file:

```
[APC]
extension=apc.so

apc.enabled = 1    # Turn APC cache on
apc.optimization  = 0    # Experimental keep off
apc.shm_segments = 1    # Shared memory segments
apc.shm_size = 256M  # Max shared memory dependent on OS
apc.ttl = 7200
apc.user_ttl  = 7200
apc.num_files_hint = 1024
apc.mmap_file_mask = /tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.enable_cli = 1 # Allow command line php to function
apc.cache_by_default  = 1 # Enabled, 0 for filters
apc.max_file_size = 10M # Maximum cached file size
apc.stat = 1 # 1 for dev, 0 for production, whether the source file is checke$
#apc.include_once_override = 1 # Use PHP5.3+ for include_once optimization
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English,

Vinicius

Comment: Use the file apc.php to check how apc performs. 256M may be low if you host several websites. Make sure APC has 20% more ram than it actually use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, my bad. The comments in the ini file weren't supposed to be with `#`, they are with `;`. I am really sorry. Now it works like a charm.